# Select query became very very very slow in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have one table which contains "133,072,194" records and I am trying to execute

```
SELECT COUNT(test) 
FROM mytable 
WHERE test = false
```

but it is taking Execution time: 128320.712 ms

I already have indexing on test column. Could you please let me know, what I can optimize or change, so my query became faster?

Because of this, my other select query is also not working.

Comment: What does the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` say?  What is the column type of `test`?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the complete execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** as [**formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1):

If there are many rows where `test` is `FALSE`, you won't be able to get an exact result faster than with a sequential scan, which is slow for big tables.

If you have only few rows that satisfy the condition, you should create a partial index:

```
CREATE INDEX mytable_notest_ind ON mytable(id) WHERE NOT test;
```

(assuming that `id` is the primary key) and keep `mytable` autovacuumed often enough that you get an index only scan.

But usually exact results for queries like this are not required.

You could calculate an estimated count from the table statistics with a query like this:

```
SELECT t.reltuples
       * (1 - t.nullfrac)
       * mcv.freq AS count_false
FROM pg_stats AS s
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(s.most_common_vals::text::boolean[],
                             s.most_common_freqs) AS mcv(val, freq)
   JOIN pg_class AS t
      ON s.tablename = t.relname
         AND s.schemaname = t.relnamespace::regnamespace::text
WHERE s.tablename = 'mytable'
  AND s.attname = 'test'
  AND mcv.val = FALSE;
```

That would be very fast.

See [my blog post](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/count-made-fast/) for more considerations about the speed of `SELECT count(*)`.

Comment: Does PostgreSQL should to perform index-only scan for such queries? Theoretically it should be as fast as in the column-oriented DBMSs.

Comment: PS: Ah yes I read the "Using an index only scan" part in the your mentioned article (thanks a lot for it BTW) It would be interesting how versioning works not only on tables data but also on indexes. Hope to read your next article about it. Thanks again.

Comment: @Abelisto Versioning is the problem: index entries are not versioned, so you can have an index only scan only if the *visibility map* knows that all tuples in a table block are visible to everybody. Then the heap doesn't have to be inspected. This requires, as I wrote, that the tables has been vacuumed recently.

Comment: @laurenz Albe, I will check count query. But, What If I need to fetch data from that table? How I can optimized it and make it faster? I need to fetch 100000 records using limit.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, Yes. I am asking this because, I need to check count and if count is more than 100000, then I need to fetch those 100000 records in loop and send it threw API post request.

Comment: Estimate the result, and if the estimate exceeds 80000, run the exact query.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, Can you help me directly on call? I am stuck on just select and count query from last 5 days.

Comment: @JimeshGajera If you want to get the 100000 records then you should to be ready: to read 100000 records from storage device (lets say if your table's row have 256 bytes then it will be ~ 25Mb) and then to pass it via network connection (for 10 Mbit/s it will be about 20 seconds).

Comment: @JimeshGajera If it is the query from the question, what is missing? If not, please open another question.